# Java/Apache POI - How can i change/set the font size in a specifc cell?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to change the font size of determined data, filled on cell in my worksheet. Let's say that cell is row 2, of the column 26. Speaking in range way, that would be: `Z2`. And the font size in 11. I want to change the font size to 72, for example.

How can I do that?

Comment: Actually is the data filled on the cell. is the font size on 11, how can i change to the 72 ? for example.

Comment: You want to change the _font_ size, not the _cell_ size?

Comment: Exactly, i updated my question

Comment: Create a font with the larger cell size applied, create a Cell Style using that Font, then apply the Cell Style to the Cell you want to be bigger?

Comment: How far have you got with this already? Can you open the worksheet? Can you save it? Can you find particular cells?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#WorkingWithFonts

Comment: Yes, i got all this. But i don't get how to set the size to cell. I'd created the font. and set the font on this size: `font.setFontHeight((short)(7.5*20));`. But how can i set this on my specific cell ?

Comment: I got now! i needed to set the style to `setFont(myfont)`. I didn't know that. Thanks @AxelRichter! Can you answer this to me check like solved ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an existing font (in the sheet or workbook) and use it as is or change it and define it for as a new font. Actual active fonts are available to you like this:  (where newCell is the cell you wish to modify)

```
Font newFont = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().findFont(oldFont.getBold(),
 oldFont.getColor(), oldFont.getFontHeight(), oldFont.getFontName(), oldFont.getItalic(),
 oldFont.getStrikeout(), oldFont.getTypeOffset(), oldFont.getUnderline());
```

To change the font and any of it's attributes:

```
Font newFont = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createFont();
     newFont.setBold(true);
     newFont.setColor(10);
     newFont.setFontHeightInPoints(72);
     newFont.setItalic(false);
     // ... etc.
```

There is quite a lot of attributes you can set, ofcourse, this is just an example.  But you are still not done, now you need to bind the font that ypou have just created/found to the actual cell you wanted.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(newFont);
```

..or alternatively use (on method creates new styles, the other modifies the style already present in the cell):

```
CellUtil.setFont(newCell, newFont);
```

Answer (score 3):

the POI HSSF Font class has two font size settings methods:

- [setFontHeight(short)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#setFontHeight%28short%29) - Set the font height in unit's of 1/20th of a point
- [setFontHeightInPoints(short)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#setFontHeightInPoints%28short%29) - Set the font height in point

Using setFontHeightInPoints is the easier one for most cases, and is recommended in the Javadocs. However, it'll only cope with whole-number font heights. That's most font sizes, but not all

To set a font height of 7.5, you'd need to change your code instead to be:

```
xtFont.setFontHeight((short)(7.5*20));
```

That uses the alternate one that takes 1/20 point sizes, so copes with non-integer values.

Comment: Ok, have i to create a font, right ? But how can set this font to my cell ?

Comment: I got now! i needed to set the style to `setFont(myfont)`. I didn't know that.